# Question about identifying a specific Radio Shack electronics kit; on topic?

Tags: discussion, identification

I've been trying to find some details online about a specific Radio Shack electronics kit I had as a young person (c. mid-80s). I can recall some details about this kit, but my Google-fu is failing. (The result set contains all sorts of refs to all those unrelated "100 in 1" kits we are all familiar with.)

Would a specific query about one of these historical kits be on topic? I'm assuming not. I can't imagine, for example, that Retrocomputing is a better fit. Both of the audiences for these SE sites overlap with the sort of hive mind I'd like to leverage.

Are such questions on topic at all?

Comment: I suggest to take the query to our [EE.SE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering).

Comment: @NickAlexeev, I suppose so. This is a pretty small subset of the hive mind is my bet, and a chat comment would end up being a little ephemeral compared to a question. I'll just use Google, or admit defeat.

Comment: what's the sku number? Ever since RadioShack was sold, the current owners nuked the online support docs.

Comment: @Passerby, no idea. I just know some kit details and the rough era. I haven't (yet) gone down the path of searching all the online catalogs.

Comment: @jdv  I'd argue that the more accute part of the EE.SE hive mind is in the chat.  That's where I take my own borderline questions.